# Siege benchmarking

Tags: webserver, benchmarking, siege

I need to benchmark apache website in linux server.
I have configured Siege and it works fine..

When I run siege on local host I get transaction rate  ie 625.00 trans/sec

```
command is : siege -b -c 200 -r 10 http://localhost
```

When I run same siege on different site I get different transaction rate i.e 99.21 trans/sec

```
siege -b -c 200 -r 10 http://apache.org
```

I want to know how my Apache server is being used in siege when I run for different sites.
please clarify this.

Comment: Your local apache server is not being used when you run siege against external sites.

Comment: Ok so Siege is just like a client and performance will be measured for targeted URL web server.

Answer (score 1):

The website in your local host is by naturally faster than the ones hosted live. The server response time will be very fast in the local server.